# Redirecting serial port keeping ability to send signals

Tags: windows-xp, remote, redirection, serial-port, signal

I have the following scenario: a laptop running Windows XP, connected to a meter through its serial port.

I need to read/write to this serial port from a remote computer (running windows 7). I also should be able to send some serial-port signals, such as a RTS.

Is there any software that gives me these capabilities?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not RDP to the laptop?

Comment: I've tried. It does not seems to make the serial port available.

Comment: I meant, why not RDP to the laptop and run whatever application you need on the laptop?  It may be the long way around, but it should do the job for you.

Comment: I need to code a driver for the meter communication and I can't run my tools on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://www.javiervalcarce.eu/wiki/Acceso_al_puerto_serie_desde_Internet

The page is in spanish but you can use Google Translate. Basically is a c# app (source & compiled)

Comment: It won't send the RTS signal, just the data. I need to be able to remotely activate the RTS pin.

Answer (score 0):

use [hterm](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/index.htm)

I know it is a german site, but you just need to click the download version. The program itself is english. Once you connected the right port you can set the RTS via a button in the lower half of the GUI. Works for me